# How to hide Windows Desktop and change desktop background color in c#?

Tags: c#, desktop, background-color, wallpaper

I need to know how to hide Windows Desktop and change desktop background color in c# and restore the previous configuration.

Any idea?

BR

Comment: What do you mean by hide desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate all desktop window with [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Collect every visible window handle.

Call [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with appropriate arguments to make the collected windows to be visible/invisible.

Take note that all created windows after this operation will be visible. To hide desktop icons you shall spy the window structure (with a tool like Spy++), get specific window handle by its class name and then call ShowWindow on the obtained widnow handle.

Of course, EnumWindows and ShowWindow must be P/Invoked. See www.pinvoke.net for getting the correct declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This shows you how to change the desktop wallpaper: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ChangeWallpaper11092005051646AM/ChangeWallpaper.aspx.